# TinyMCE style conflict

Tags: css, tinymce

Something in my CSS seem to be changing tinyMCE's buttons :
[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this ?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What does Firebug's "Inspect Element" say?

Comment: the buttons seem to have a big margin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is impossible to solve without seeing the full CSS.

The easiest way to find out what the problem is is to inspect the element, in Firefox or Chrome using Right-Click -> "Inspect element" (Firebug needs to be installed in Firefox for this).

The style inspector will tell you where the additional margin or padding comes from.